# Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am Asheesh from India. I am new to programming in data science. While completing a project I encountered an error "***Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous***" while running following code.

```
ggplot(data = cyclistic_data ) + geom_bar(aes(x = member_casual, y= ride_length))
```

I am also sharing my all code chunks if you may need a reference

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

setwd("C:\\Users\\sashe\\Desktop\\Data Analytics\\8_Capstone\\New folder")

data_2021_6 <- read.csv("202106-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_7 <- read.csv("202107-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_8 <- read.csv("202108-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_9 <- read.csv("202109-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_10 <- read.csv("202110-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_11 <- read.csv("202111-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2021_12 <- read.csv("202112-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2022_1 <- read.csv("202201-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2022_2 <- read.csv("202202-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2022_3 <- read.csv("202203-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2022_4 <- read.csv("202204-divvy-tripdata.csv")
data_2022_5 <- read.csv("202205-divvy-tripdata.csv")

combined_data<- rbind(data_2021_6, data_2021_7, data_2021_8, data_2021_9, data_2021_10, data_2021_11, data_2021_12, data_2022_1, data_2022_2, data_2022_3, data_2022_4, data_2022_5)

combined_data$ride_length <- difftime(combined_data$ended_at, combined_data$started_at)

#create columnds for: day of week, month, day, year, time
combined_data$date <- as.Date(combined_data$started_at) #default format is yyyy-mm-dd, use start date
combined_data$day_of_week <- wday(combined_data$started_at) #calculate the day of the week 
combined_data$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(combined_data$date), "%A") #create column for day of week
combined_data$month <- format(as.Date(combined_data$date), "%m")#create column for month
combined_data$day <- format(as.Date(combined_data$date), "%d") #create column for day
combined_data$year <- format(as.Date(combined_data$date), "%Y") #create column for year

#clean the data
combined_data <- na.omit(combined_data) #remove rows with NA values
combined_data <- distinct(combined_data) #remove duplicate rows 
combined_data <- combined_data[!(combined_data$ride_length <=0),] #remove where ride_length is 0 or negative
combined_data <- combined_data %>%  #remove columns not needed: ride_id, start_station_id, end_station_id, start_lat, start_long, end_lat, end_lng
  select(-c(ride_id, start_station_id, end_station_id,start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng)) 

cyclistic_data <- combined_data

ggplot(data = cyclistic_data ) + geom_bar(aes(x = member_casual, y= ride_length))
```

I would be grateful, if you may help me on this.

Comment: Is it an error or just a warning? Is a plot produced?

Comment: The issue is most likely that you use `geom_bar` with both an `x` and `y` aesthetic which will result in an error `stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.`. Try with `geom_col` instead. `Don't know how to automatically ... ` is (most likely) just a warning.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for the explanation. it worked. Yes, Don't know how..... was a warning

Comment: @AllanCameron It was just a warning.  Thank you